# Determine affine linear f $\in C^1(R)$ such that the differential form is exact

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms

Determine affine linear function $f$ such that the differential form $\omega$ is exact, where
$$
\omega (x,y) = (6x^2y+2y^3+2yf(x^2+y^2))dx + (3y^2-2xf(x^2+y^2))dy.
$$
I started the exercise but at some point I can't continue.
I calculated the partial derivatives and imposed them to be equal.
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}F_1  & = 6x^2+6y^2+2f(x^2+y^2)+4y^2f'(x^2+y^2) \\
& = -2f(x^2+y^2)-4x^2f'(x^2+y^2) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}F_2
\end{split}
$$
Doing the math I found
$$
6(x^2+y^2)+4f(x^2+y^2)+4(x^2+y^2)f'(x^2+y^2)= 0
$$
The problem is in solving this differential equation.
I have placed $x^2+y^2 = s$ so
$$
6(s)+4f(s)+4(s)f'(s)= 0
$$
can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from your last line:
$$6s+4f(s)+4sf'(s)= 0$$
$$f(s)+sf'(s)= -\dfrac 32s$$
$$(sf(s))'=-\dfrac 32 s$$
Integrate.
$$sf(s)=-\dfrac 34 s^2+C$$
$$f(s)=-\dfrac 34 s+\dfrac Cs$$

---

$f$ is required to be linear affine, I bet $C=0$ is the right choice. –
@Daniele Tampieri

Comment: +1. And since $f$ is required to be linear affine, I bet $C=0$ is the right choice.

Comment: thanks you're right @DanieleTampieri  I added your comment to my answer...